# Facebook share link post image pulling through

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress

Hey Guys on my single posts I have a share button.. The problem is the share button doesn't add the featured image from wordpress but shows an array of images.. I need my posts image to show.. I dont know any other way or how to use it wit php this is my code..

```
    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
            $image_share = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-share' );
            $image_post = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'counsel' );
            $image_full = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'full' );
            $comments_count = wp_count_comments( $post->ID );?>
            <h3 class="post-info-title"><p class="poster-title"><?php the_title();?></p>


            <p class="post-comment"><span class="post-comment-text">Comments</span><span class="post-commment-num"><?php echo $comments_count->approved ;?></span><img class="img-comment" src="<?php echo 'http://edge.beresponsive.net/wp-content/themes/edge-church/images/comment-img.png';?>" /></p>
            <p class="share-link-holder share-news"><a class="share-links" onclick="window.open('//player.vimeo.com/v2/video/<?php the_field('vimeo_link');?>/share/facebook', 'Facebook Share', 'width=400, height=300'); return false;" href="javascript:void(0)">Share This</a></p></h3>
            <div class="news_holder">
                    <a class="news_img" href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
                    </a>
                    <div class="blur post-cont">
                        <div class="blurb-text"> <?php the_content(); ?></div>
                    </div>
            </div>

      <?php endwhile; ?>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the feature image in template into the head.
Like this:

```
<head>
 <meta property="og:image" content="http://absolute_url_to_image/image.jpg" />
</head>
```

Just with php to make it dynamic.

So:

```
<head>
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );?>" />
</head>
```

Comment: How do you add the feautured image to the meta tag.. If it's a post you need the featured image url not an absolute url.. Im confused

Comment: I updated my answer with a working code. You need to edit your head template or post template for this to work.

It get's the current post's featured image and put it inside the meta property.

Comment: Thank you so much my problem is how do you get the featured image to pull through outside the loop.. If i look in my page source it shows an empty.. this is whats in my page source <meta property="og:image" content="" />